# In house vs home visits

Tags: phrases

When do we use in house acupuncture, and home visit acupuncture in a situation where  organisation works within itself and only for that organisation? But at the same time does house calls?

Answer (score 1):

This is rather a quirky aspect of English and might seem rather strange to foreign speakers.

> In-house acupuncture

This means that acupuncture is done on-site.  This does not have anything to do with visiting other people's homes.

> Home-visit/house-visit acupuncture
>
> In-Home Acupuncture
>
> Acupuncture done by House-calls

These mean you visit someone's house and do acupuncture.  The latter two sound the least awkward of the three to me.

Comment: If you worked for a complementary therapy centre which had partners and employees who were acupuncturists but also used free-lance contractors sometimes then treatments given by partners or employees would be in-house treatments and those given by contractors would be contract treatments. Whether the treatments were given at the centre, in the client's home or at some other location would not matter in this respect.

Answer (score 0):

"In house" tends to be used to refer to a product or service which could potentially have been made by a third party but was instead made by you/your business. E.g.

> Our marketing team uses our own in-house software

or

> Come buy our ovens, all parts are made in-house.

In your case, you definitely want to go with "Home Vist".